# img tag is not working properly in actionscript3 TextField

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, textfield

I have a TextField.
Here is a snippet:

```
this.textField = new TextField();
this.textField.defaultTextFormat = font.format;
this.textField.selectable = true;
this.textField.border = true;
this.textField.wordWrap = true;
this.textField.multiline = true;
```

And here is the method to add new line to the textField box:

```
this.textField.htmlText = 'some text <IMG SRC="http://gravitatestudio.com/wp-content/themes/gravitate/images/facebook.png">';
```

The issue is that an image is always placed UNDER text instead of the END OF THE TEXT.

Here is the trace(this.textField.htmlText) after html text has been added:

```
<P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="12" COLOR="#FFFFFF" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">some text <FONT SIZE="2"><IMG SRC="http://gravitatestudio.com/wp-content/themes/gravitate/images/facebook.png"> </FONT></FONT></P>
```

Also I need to add an image to any side of the text like a chat message using smiles (left, middle, right side of the text).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextField html text is very limited and thats why Adobe released TLFTextFields which will give you much more control over the layout of elements in the field.  I have personally used it and have made entire chats out of one textfield with images, links etc.

resource: 
adobe: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/text/TLFTextField.html

tutorial:
http://flashsimulations.com/2010/09/10/handling-image-loading-in-tlf-textflow-and-textfield/